# Storing directed acyclic graphs effectively in PDAs

Tags: pda

I’m trying to implement a directed acyclic graph structure where each node and it’s related path’s are stored in different pda’s. I need to add security checks so that users can’t try to make a child parent of it’s own parent. 
A is parent of B: A -> B 
The contract must not allow the call for make_parent(B, A): B -X> A 
This is possible if A is the direct parent of the B but if the structure is something like so 
A -> C -> B 
The contract allows make_parent(B, A): B -> A, since B doesn’t appear on A’s children 
Because I can only access the given PDA’s in the contract call, it is not possible to access the whole graph in my situation and I am trying to find another solution for this task. Can you help me find a different solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that I can make a seperate PDA for each graph that is generated, and store the whole graph there and easily make comparisons to check duplicates.